# find a checkbox from a tr tag and select it in Selenium(java)

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing, checkbox

I used the following code to retrieve the row that I want to select in selenium:

```
WebElement row = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[contains(.,'prod1')]"));
```

As a result, I get the following row:

```
<th width="18px">
                <input class="selectedProducts" id="checkbox-37640" onclick="markedProductsHandler.toggleMarkProduct(this,37640)" type="checkbox">
            </th>


            <th style="white-space:nowrap; width:573px;" align="left">

<a class="maxTextSize" style="width:530px" href="product.html?id=37640&amp;rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs">aa prod1</a>
            </th>

            <th style="white-space:nowrap;" align="right" width="140px">

                    <a href="product-edit.html?id=37640&amp;rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs"><img src="_images/icons/pencil.png?rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs" title="Edit"></a> &nbsp;


                        <input name="favoriteid" class="favoriteAction" value="37640" type="hidden">
                        <input name="favoriteaction" class="favoriteAction" value="add" type="hidden">
                        <a href="javascript:" onclick="onFavoriteAction(this)">
                            <img src="_images/icons/star_grey.png?rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs" alt="Watch product" title="Watch product">
                        </a> &nbsp;

        <form action="product-pdf.html?rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs" method="post">
            <input name="export" value="pdf" type="hidden">
            <input name="id" value="37640" type="hidden">
            <a href="javascript:" onclick="javascript: $(this).parent().submit();"><img src="_images/icons/page_white_acrobat.png?rm7zz5c=ZBOeBCOAs" title="Download as PDF"></a> &nbsp;
        </form>
            </th>
```

Now I would like to select the checkbox:

```
row.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

but I get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: According to the exception, it seems like the checkbox is hidden. Are there any styles like `visibility:hidden;` or `display:none` for class `selectedProducts`?https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException.java

Comment: can you tell us the result of `row.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")).isDisplayed()`? + try to add waiter for waiting till checkbox will become visible

Comment: Hi, the result is false

Comment: In your sample HTML, where exactly is there a `tr`? Everything is a `th`.

Comment: Yes they look like this and selenium finds and returns this html. isnt it fine?

Comment: @SiKing nice point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add **explicit wait** till element is visible. If element is hidden permanently (for some reasons?) try following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = row.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

One of the ideas if everything would fail: you can fire following method via javascript: `markedProductsHandler.toggleMarkProduct`

Comment: :( Last chance: can you share the link to page?

Comment: Thanks but It is not possible. how can it help?

Comment: OK, it's fine. Maybe you missed something in question description. Maybe there are 2 elements on the page and you found incorrect one. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I provided the returned row(web element), isnt it enough?

Comment: When I debug this test case, I get empty space for element.getAttribute("innerHTML");

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Tried fluentWait ?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf
               (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"))));
```

Check if it will throw an exception.

Comment: Hi, this is the result org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for visibility of [[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS ] -> xpath: //input[@type='checkbox']]

Answer (score 0):

I think the id of the checkbox is dynamic so you should generate xpath like following:

```
row.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id[starts-with(., 'checkbox')]]")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i still get error org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with